# STM32 USB Host plugin notification on Android/IOS phones

Tags: android, embedded, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4, usb-hostcontroller

I have successfully developed firmware for USB Host/USB OTG on STM32F4 Discovery board and successfully tested serial communication with the phone via an Android app. I am attempting a custom notification of my discovery board connected to the Android phones.

Is there a message format that can trigger a custom notification on Android phones?

Comment: Have you seen that anywhere before?

Comment: I have seen like this https://youtu.be/FdQLTlJIi5U